# GA4 not displaying page path correctly for a Vue.js SPA with GTM

Tags: vue.js, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I have a Vue.js single page application (SPA) that uses Google Analytics 4 (GA4) with Google Tag Manager (GTM) to track user interactions. I'm having trouble getting the page path to display correctly in GA4. Instead of showing the complete page path including the URL fragment (e.g., "#/admin" or "#/home"), it only shows the root ("/").

I have added the following code to my Vue.js router configuration to push the page_view event with the correct page_location and page_path to the data layer:

```
router.afterEach((to) => {
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    window.dataLayer.push({
        event: "page_view",
        page_location: window.location.href,
        page_path: to.path,
    });
});
```

The GA4 debug view shows the correct page path, but it's not displayed properly in the GA4 "Pages and screens" report.

What could be causing this issue, and what are the next steps to properly display the page path, including the URL fragment, in GA4 "Pages and screens" report?

Comment: How is your tag in GTM setup? You have page_location and page_path in your dataLayer, but it depends on how you have hooked those variables into the tag i.e. GA4 needs the fully qualified url (page_location in your case), whereas Universal analytics just needed the page path. If you are using the page_path in your tag, then you won't get the hash part and also won't get the domain, protocol and querystring parameters.